# python c api, how can I add function to class which defined in c layer

Tags: cpython

I defined a type spam.Foo follow [Defining New Types](https://docs.python.org/zh-cn/2.7/extending/newtypes.html).

Which like this.

```
PyObject *m;
m = Py_InitModule(MODULE_NAME, Spam_methods);

int rst = PyModule_AddObject(m, "Foo", (PyObject *)&FooPyType);
if (rst == -1) {
    throw std::runtime_error("PyModule_AddObject(Foo) failed");
}
```

And the Foo PyTypeObject is like this:

```
PyTypeObject FooPyType = {
    PyVarObject_HEAD_INIT(&PyType_Type, 0)
    "spam.Foo",
    sizeof(Foo),
    0,
    0,
    0,
    0,
    0,
    0,
    0,
    0,
    0,
    0,
    0,
    0,
    reinterpret_cast<reprfunc>(FooType_str),
    0,
    0,
    0,
    Py_TPFLAGS_DEFAULT,
    "The spam Foo",
    0,
    0,
    0,
    0,
    0,
    0,
    FooType_methods,
    nullptr,
    FooType_getSet
};
```

Now I want create a new function in python code:

```
from spam import Foo
setattr(Foo, "bar", lambda self: "Hello from bar")
```

But it throw an error: `can't set attributes of built-in/extension type 'spam.Foo'`.

How can I do this.

Comment: Can you update the question with the relevant part of the `C` code?

Comment: Hello, @AbdulNiyasPM. I have already added the c part code.